# MySQL - Error 1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to create tables for my database and this error is haunting me. I've checked the type.. they are the same yet I get this error. Any help is appreciated.

Table consoles:

```
CREATE TABLE consoles (
consoleid int(5) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
name varchar(25),
lp int(10));
```

Table game:

```
CREATE TABLE game (gamecode int(5) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
consolename char(10), 
price int(6), 
points int(5));
```

Table loyaltypoints:

```
CREATE TABLE loyaltypoints (voucherid int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
totalpoints int(5));
```

Table user: (cannot add foreign key constraint error while creating)

```
CREATE TABLE user (
userid int(5) AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
lp int(5),
role char(10) default 'user',
gameid int(10),
FOREIGN KEY (gameid) REFERENCES game(gamecode),
FOREIGN KEY (lp) REFERENCES loyaltypoints(totalpoints)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because totalpoints in loyaltypoints is not unique. I got it to work by changing the loyalypoints table add to:

```
CREATE TABLE loyaltypoints (voucherid int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
totalpoints int(5) UNIQUE);
```

Usually foreign keys refer to the primary key of another table.

You also have gamecode as int(5) and gameid as int(10). That didn't cause an error when I ran it, but they should be the same length.

Comment: Great answer! Yes, I will keep the lengths in mind :) Thank you